# How can I remove spaces and blank lines from text? [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble formatting a string. I have tried several ways but it keeps printing with line breaks, I leave you an example below.

```py
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import re

rutaFichero = sys.argv[1]
rutaFicheroAComparar = sys.argv[2]
print(rutaFichero)
print(rutaFicheroAComparar)
try:
  with open(rutaFichero,'r') as fichero:
    for n in fichero :
      n.strip()
      n.replace('\n', '').replace(' ','')
      re.sub(r'\s+', '',n)
      resultado = subprocess.run(f"grep '{n}' {rutaFicheroAComparar}", shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
      ##debugging
      print(f"grep {n} {rutaFicheroAComparar}")
      print("Salida del comando:")
      print(resultado.stdout)
      print("Código de salida:", resultado.returncode)
      ##debugging
##      if resultado.returncode == 1:
##        print('No existe')
##      else:
##        print(f"{n} existe en {rutaFicheroAComparar}")
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

This line of code is responsible for debugging what is happening.

```
print(f"grep {n} {rutaFicheroAComparar}")
```

and in my terminal it is printing like this:

```
"grep meloinvento

 topicsStrimzi.txt"
```

when I would like it to print like this: `"grep meloinvento topicsStrimzi.txt"`

When I put that line break, the grep command interprets it in another way and breaks the execution.

Thanks a lot.

I try this lines of code:

```
      n.strip()
      n.replace('\n', '').replace(' ','')
      re.sub(r'\s+', '',n)
```

But not works.

Comment: Neither of these works in-place. You need to assign the result

Comment: n = n.replace('\n', '').replace(' ','') .

Comment: str is an immutable entity you cannot modified that type in-place thus "replace" and the others will always return something which corresponds to what you want as @buran said you sould re-assign the result.

Answer (score 0):

re.split is probably better to use in this case.

```
with open(r"data.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lst = re.split(r'\s+|\n', line)
        line = " ".join(lst)
        print(line)

grep meloinvento topicsStrimzi.txt
```